# FBX 3D Model Importer app crashed with OVR Integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-model, oculus-runtime

**GOAL**

I imported  package and OVR Integration package.

I want to show model from web url and show 3d model in Oculus.

**ISSUE**

App crashed and quit when model appear after model loading done.

Model Loader Library is working fine in Android Phone but crashed in oculus.

**CONTENT**

I use Built-in and Unity2022.3.8f1. I am using Meta XR Integration 60.0 with TriLib 2 - Model Loading Package v2.1.4.

This library is working fine in Android Phone but crashed in oculus.

[Importer Assets Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PANor.png)

I tried for set Importer Assets Setting but It is not working and still crashed and quit.

Please help me